# How to get systemd user unit logs?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm using `loginctl --enable-linger USERNAME` to activate user services. The unit files are stored in `$HOME/.config/systemd/...`.

Now a service that worked before starts (I can see it in process listing) and after some seconds it ends. I want to know, why it is stopped. I assume it crashes and gives some error output. Where can I see this error output or some logging of this systemd user unit?

Answer (score 3):

The `--user` flag is needed to talk to the user's instance of systemd rather than the system instance.

Use `systemctl --user status myunit.service` to see a summary of the unit's status (along with the last few lines of the journal for that service) or `journalctl --user -u myunit.service` to read the full journal for that unit.

Comment: This has to be run in the users context right?

I found another solution: `loginctl user-status USERNAME`

Comment: Just tried you solution but it didn't work: `$ systemctl --user status 
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hm, interesting. For what it's worth, the `--user` switch only works if you're logged in as the user you're asking about. On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine with systemd 249, the user socket is stored in `/run/user/1000/bus` (where `1000` is my UID). Do you have anything there?

Comment: If you need to check it while logged in as a different user, run `machinectl shell other-user@` and then `systemctl --user ...` inside it. `su other-user` doesn't give you the right environment.